# Does this attic insulation look like asbestos or mineral wool?

Tags: wiring, insulation, light-fixture, safety, asbestos

My house was built in 1962. I'm trying to replace a ceiling light fixture with a ceiling fan by retrofitting the hole. Unfortunately there seems to be quite a bit of this gray, stringy, slightly shiny insulation in the attic and falling out a bit. Any suggestions as to whether this is asbestos? After some reading, I'm hoping it's mineral/rock wool, but I'd like a second opinion if you don't mind. Thanks!

[image: asbestos-like insulation]

[image: asbestos image 2]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nobody can tell if a fiber is asbestos without lab testing.

Comment: That's what all the mineral wool in my house looks like but there's really no good reason to guess.  Look up local asbestos testing places online, put some of this stuff in a baggy, and take it down there to find out for sure.

Comment: I'm wondering why there isn't a box in the ceiling.

Comment: @RMDman I removed the existing box in order to replace it with a retrofit ceiling fan box :) I took this picture just after I removed the existing box.

Comment: Update: I sent samples in for a test, and they came back saying it is indeed mineral wool! Thanks for the help, everyone. Glad to have this peace of mind.

Answer (score 6):

No idea what it is. Could be asbestos. Could be mineral wool. Could be some other natural fibers. Could be some other man-made fibers (e.g., fiberglass). Could be almost anything.

**But it doesn't matter.**

Why? Your exposure is extremely limited. Except for a few things (certain really potent poisons, plutonium, etc.) limited casual contact is really not a big deal. And if you are concerned:

- Put on gloves and throw them away after the job is done.
- Put on a mask. Ideally K95, but realistically for small scale exposure even a basic mask (which most of us now have boxes of lying around the house for some reason) will block the vast majority of particles that might come off of old insulation or building materials.
- Clean up well afterwards and throw away the cleaning materials (paper towels, rags, etc.).

Most of the people who are affected by asbestos are the ones who worked with it, without proper protective equipment, day after day for **years**. An hour of fiddling around with a light fixture isn't usually a big deal. And this may not even be asbestos anyway.

Keep in mind that the big risk with asbestos is *breathing it in*. And there are actually a lot of other small fibers and chemicals and dust that you really don't want to breathe in either. So *mask up* is a reasonable step one, whether it is asbestos or not. How much more beyond that depends on your level of concern.

Comment: This "answer" is dangerously wrong - even a small exposure to asbestos can be a problem, and in many jurisdictions there is a legal requirement to report any find.

Comment: @MikeB  You are right for a small percentage of people exposed to some types of asbestos.  For most people wearing a simple mask will protect them.

Comment: @MikeB plutonium isn’t that dangerous - asbestos is. The harm from plutonium is dose related. So is the harm from asbestos: unless you happen to be one of those people whose genetics predispose you to mesothelioma - then one exposure is enough.

Comment: Of course, I’m assuming you don’t *eat* the plutonium- it’s highly a highly toxic chemical irrespective of its radioactivity.

Comment: Lets see - one of my in-laws died from mesothelioma from one exposure machining transite. The other died from complications of lung cancer from inhaling a plutonium particle. Be respectful of hazards and mitigate the risks properly. Proper PPE is much easier to get than it was 50-60 years ago when those exposures happened.

Answer (score 3):

### You can’t tell by looking

However, given the date of construction, it’s entirely possible - the damn stuff was ubiquitous. Anything before 1990 is likely to contain it, anything up to 2003 might contain it. If you want piece of mind, you can get a hygienist to test it.

In the meantime, [treat](https://www.safework.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0014/50081/How-to-manage-and-control-asbestos-in-the-workplace-COP.pdf) it like it is. Asbestos is nasty. For the vast majority of people, risk is exposure related meaning that occasional exposure over a lifetime is unlikely to cause harm. However, for a small minority of people with the right (wrong) physiology, one exposure can cause mesothelioma - you’ll know if that’s you in 30-40 years.

Proper PPE is disposable chem suits, masks, goggles and gloves - all should be available at any reasonably sized hardware or safety store. Seperate out the clothes you wear under the suit and launder them separately - preferably in a dedicated washing machine. For your purposes it might be cheaper to buy cheap clothes for underneath that you just dispose of, or, since no one is going to see, go naked under the suit.

Clean up dust with a dust pan and broom and wipe down surfaces with a damp sponge. Double bag all of the PPE and clean up gear in heavy duty plastic that you tape shut with duct tape (or duck tape depending on what it’s called where you are) before disposal and shower thoroughly. You shouldn’t dispose of it in general landfill - it costs but it should be taken to the waste disposal facility and disposed of as asbestos.

If you do want to get it tested, while wearing the PPE double bag a small sample in zip lock bags that you then wipe down and take it to the lab.